# How to take the 3rd element of each nested list but if 3rd doesnt exist put null?

Tags: python, list

My list looks like the following;

```
list = [['a', 'b', 'x'], ['a', 'd', 'r'], ['a', 'c']]
```

what I want to do is extract the 3rd element of each sub-list but on the last one because there is only 2 input "null"

This is what I have tried already.

```
try:
    lst1 = [item[2] for item in list]
except IndexError:
    lst1 = ['' for item in list]
print(lst1)
```

expected output would be the following;

```
lst1 = ['x', 'r', '']
```

Comment: I think you need to edit either question title or post (one contains 4, other 3)

Comment: @josh0798 Please mark the most helpful answer as accepted, if your question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator here, like:

```
result = [item[2] if len(item) > 2 else '' for item in mylist]
```

for example:

```
>>> [item[2] if len(item) > 2 else '' for item in mylist]
['x', 'r', '']
```

> **Note**: please do *not* give your variables names of builtins, since that will override the references to these builtins. For example use `mylist`, instead of <s>`list`</s>.

Comment: Thanks, How can improve this for when the max size of nested list is unknown? The following is an an extreme case as I know there will never be more than 6 in a list but what is the best way to shorten this.                                                                            lst1 = [item[0] for item in list]
lst2 = [i[1] if len(i) > 1 else '' for i in list]
lst3 = [i[1] if len(i) > 2 else '' for i in list]
lst4 = [i[1] if len(i) > 3 else '' for i in list]
lst5 = [i[1] if len(i) > 4 else '' for i in list]
lst6 = [i[1] if len(i) > 5 else '' for i in list]

Comment: You just parameterize the index you want to obtain, like `[item[k] if len(item) > k else '' for item in mylist]`.

Comment: What would I have to assign "[item[k] if len(item) > k else '' for item in mylist]" to to get multiple lists, would it be str(lst + k) = [item[k] if len(item) > k else '' for item in mylist]?

Comment: You define a function `def obtain(mylist, k): [item[k] if len(item) > k else '' for item in mylist]`, and then call it with `result_1 = obtain(mylist,1)`, `result_2 = obtain(mylist,2)`, etc. or you can use a `for` loop where you iterate over the indices for example.

Answer (score 1):

You may go with simple list comprehension:

```
lst = [['a', 'b', 'x'], ['a', 'd', 'r'], ['a', 'c']]
res = [i[2] if len(i) > 2 else '' for i in lst]
print(res)    # ['x', 'r', '']
```

The condition `i[2] if len(i) > 2 else ''` ensures the 3rd item `i[2]` (Python uses zero-based indexing) exists only if length of a sublist has more than 2 items `len(i) > 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a loop and try-except as well, similar to how you attempted:

```
lst1 = []
for item in list:
    try:
        lst1.append(item[2])
    except IndexError:
        lst1.append("")
```

If you want to have the index where you want to cut as a variable, you can choose to have this as a nice function:

```
def nth_element(n):
    lst1 = []
    for item in list:
        try:
            lst1.append(item[2])
        except IndexError:
            lst1.append("")
    return lst1
```

Now you can enter any `n` and just call this function: `nth_element(0)` gives you the first elements of each list, `nth_element(1)` second elements, `nth_element(2)` third elements, etc.

Per your comments, you can collect all lists of `n`th elements, up to `m`, inside another list as follows: `[nth_element(i) for i in range(m)]`.

Note: Don't name your variables with built-ins. So instead of list, name it lst or my_list or list0 etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next` and `iter` like in the following

```
>>> lst = [['a', 'b', 'x'], ['a', 'd', 'r'], ['a', 'c']]
>>> n = 2
>>> [next(iter(l[n:]), '')  for l in lst]
['x', 'r', '']
```